# Cardinality of Quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

For any integer $n$, let $I_{n}$ denote the ideal {$m ∈ Z$ | $m^{r}$∈ $nZ$ for some $r ≥ 1$}.

What is the cardinality of the quotient ring $Z$/($I_{63}$ ∩ $I_{84}$)?

I am unable to understand the structure of ideal $I_{n}$.

I tried constructing $I_{63}$. It comes out to be at first sight to be as {$0,63$}. And similarly, $I_{84}$ comes out to be {$0,84$}. But It is incorrect as clarified by the fact in the comments, that any ideal of Z is of the $kZ$ and must have infinite elements for non zero k.

Please give some hints on how to approach this question.

Comment: Is $\{0,63\}$ an ideal of $\Bbb Z$? This seems wrong. The only ideals are of the form $k\Bbb Z$, and contain infinitely many elements for $k\neq 0$.

Comment: $63^5$ belongs to $I_{63}$ by definition, so it cannot be $I_{63}=\{0,63\}$. What you're defining is the radical ideal of $(63)$ (the ideal generated by $63$). You can actually prove that if $n=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$ (with $p_1,\cdots,p_k$ distinct primes), then $I_n$ is the ideal generated by $p_1\cdots p_k$ (Exercise). In this case, $63$ is prime, while $84=2^2\cdot 3\cdot 7$, so...

Comment: Yes. You seem to be correct. Just that 63 is not prime.Can you provide me, with the source from where you provided me this result?